# How can I add days to the logic in my shell script?

Tags: shell

I am on AIX c shell and trying to add days.
I have

```
#!/bin/sh    

Today=`date +%u` # which gives me 5    
Tomorrow='expr ${Today} + 1' # do nothing
```

could you please let me know how to increase day of the week by 1?

Comment: Why did you mention the C shell when your script invokes the Bourne shell? `/bin/sh` is the Bourne shell. `/bin/csh` is the C shell.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you put your `expr` statement in single quotes, which prevents the shell from replacing `${Today}` with `5`, and prevents it from executing the `expr` instruction (it just stores the whole expression as a string in the `Tomorrow` variable).

You probably want something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh    

Today=`date +%u` # which gives me 5    
Tomorrow=`expr ${Today} + 1` # works
echo $Tomorrow # outputs 6
```